# Does istio proxy manipulate headers of incoming/outgoing requests by default?

Tags: kubernetes, istio, istio-sidecar

With default configurations, does istio-proxy(sidecar) manipulate incoming/outgoing requests from the application container?

Comment: There are a couple of cases like [distributed tracing](https://istio.io/latest/docs/tasks/observability/distributed-tracing/overview/#trace-context-propagation) and [mutual TLS](https://istio.io/latest/docs/tasks/security/authentication/authn-policy/#auto-mutual-tls) that add headers; is there something specific you're looking for?  How does this relate to the application code you're writing?

Comment: I noticed some of the headers including content type were malformed. I have verified that these are not from the application itself, so was wondering if Istio added them... Now that there were no distributed tracing or mTLS configured, these must probably be coming from the client making these requests. Thanks for the response @DavidMaze

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Comment posted by [David Maze](https://stackoverflow.com/users/10008173/david-maze) is good and this could be part of an answer:

> There are a couple of cases like [distributed tracing](https://istio.io/latest/docs/tasks/observability/distributed-tracing/overview/#trace-context-propagation) and [mutual TLS](https://istio.io/latest/docs/tasks/security/authentication/authn-policy/#auto-mutual-tls) that add headers;

These are the two methods by which you can manipulate the headers using istio. Additionally, in the official documentation you can find a [simple tutorial](https://istio.io/v1.4/docs/tasks/policy-enforcement/control-headers/) with yaml files, where you will learn how to manage headers. It is also displayed how you can create [request header operation](https://istio.io/v1.4/docs/tasks/policy-enforcement/control-headers/#request-header-operations). However, take into account that this tutorial is based on an outdated version of Istio and you should use the latest supported version for your solution.